# How to access a static function from a component instance in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with a number of static functions defined for it(through the `statics` property in the component definition). I need to access one of these static functions in the lifecycle method `componentDidMount`. I tried the following

- `this` object has a `statics` property, but that seems to be `null` always
- `this` object also has a `_owner`, which in turn has a `statics` property. Again, that is always `null`

Then I tried `this.constructor.<static_function>`. This worked for me. I just wanted to know whether this is the right way to access static functions defined for a component or is there something else that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 7):

Accessing your static methods and properties via `this.constructor` is fine. You can also access them via `ComponentClass.<static>`.

Comment: What do you mean *via `this.constructor`*. How is that?

Comment: @Green e.g. You can use `this.constructor.myStaticFunction()` to access a function declared in your component with `static myStaticFunction() { }`.

Answer (score 6):

Why not define the functions in the outer scope, and just export them in the `statics` property. Something like this:

```
var foo = function() { ... }
var bar = function() { ... }

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar
  }
});
```

Now the static functions are accessible anywhere in the scope of the component code.

Comment: I usually use this method, perhaps there is better? I don't know - but this works just fine.  Naturally you want to make sure that your component is scoped correctly so you don't leak, but that should be occuring anyway!